# All forms can't be opened via "View Designer"

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2010

I had a project of C#.NET which has some forms.
I needed to create a similar application with it, so i copied the project and changed the project name to new one.
The new project worked fine. Could be built, no errors.
But then i realized that i couldn't edit all of forms because of this problem.

> To prevent possible data loss before loading the designer, the
>   following errors must be resolved:

Under the line, this error message was printed.

> Cannot find type
>   System.Runtime.InteropServices.ClassInterfaceAttribute in module
>   mscorlib.dll.

Here is the Call Stack.

> Instances of this error (1)
>   1.   Hide Call Stack
>   at Microsoft.MetadataReader.MetadataOnlyAssembly.GetType(String name,
>   Boolean throwOnError, Boolean ignoreCase)
>   ...
>   atMicrosoft.VisualStudio.Design.Serialization.CodeDom.VSCodeDomDesignerLoader.DeferredLoadHandler.Microsoft.VisualStudio.TextManager.Interop.IVsTextBufferDataEvents.OnLoadCompleted(Int32
>   fReload)

All forms get identical errors.
I have no idea to fix this..
Anyone has a solution?

Visual Studio 2010
Windows 7 32bit

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Compare references in original project with new one and add anything that's missing. Also check namespace name, you may have to do a find/replace for the entire project to change namespace and some other references.

Comment: Thank you for your advice. I've checked whether there are any missing libs, but all references were fine. Also i've searched old project name in new project, but all relevant places seem to have been replaced. However, Oddly, i realized i could find the old project name by windows explor's search. I got five results as matched file, but none of them has the word in the file, nor in the file name....

Comment: I resolved this issue. The problem was another "mscorlib.dll" which i added intentionally into this project interfered a function showing "View Designer". After i've removed the another "mscorlib.dll", "View Designer" worked fine. In addition, this problem seems to happen only in VS2010. I didn't get this error in VS2008.